# Page not found error if I put www before the url

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, certbot

I've a strange problem with my website. If I use enographiae.com I can have access to the site but if I use www.enographiae.com it shown me

> 404 Not Found nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

How I can fix it?

**UPDATE:**
On my server there is certbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this lines added from Certbot at the end of the Nginx configuration file:

```
.
.
.
server {
    if ($host = enographiae.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
.
.
.
```

With this:

```
.
.
.
server {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # managed by Certbot
.
.
.
```

the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you redirect www.enographiae.com to enographiae.com in your DNS records? You need to create CNAME alias (www.enographiae.com) for enographiae.com

Comment: You probably need to t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶n̶g̶i̶n̶x̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶e̶r̶v̶e̶r̶.̶ ̶I̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶u̶s̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶l̶o̶c̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶/̶e̶t̶c̶/̶n̶g̶i̶n̶x̶/̶n̶g̶i̶n̶x̶.̶c̶o̶n̶f̶ ̶.  file in the directory /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default. Just edit the line where it says server_name 198.xxx.xxx(your IP adress) followed by enographiae.com, add www.enographiae.com below it

Comment: When I've started Nginx on my server this was the first thing that I did: `...server {

    listen 80;
    server_name enographiae.com www.enographiae.com;...`

Comment: post your sites-enabled/default config, don't forget to restart nginx after changes